# Springboot Micro Service and Mongo container

Tags: docker, microservices

I have a Spring boot Micro service  that calls to a Mongo DB.

To set it up in my Local Machine. I set up a Mongo DB Container in my local docker at localhost:27017.

I tried to stand up the Spring boot Micro service application at port 8082 and it was successful.

I now want to run both of them in Docker this.

I am unable to get the app running in docker

Steps:

1. Docker Container for Mongo

`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongo -d mongo:latest`

2. Built the Image for my Spring Boot App

`docker build -f Dockerfile -t myApp .`

Docker File :

```
FROM dtr-<My Corp Base Image>
ADD build/libs/app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

3 . Bring up the App in container and link to Mongo DB

```
docker run -p 8082:8082 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local" --name myApp-containerName --link=mongo  myApp-ImageName
```

My Error:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'zzzzz' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/uscm/ratabase/service/ZZZZ.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'ZZZZZZ': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out
>   after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
>   WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,
>   servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
>   socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}];
>   nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after
>   30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
>   WritableServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN,
>   servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
>   socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
>   2019-06-13 15:49:14.769 ERROR [ZZZZZZ,,,] 1 --- [ main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

Comment: I think The spring boot container is trying to connect to localhost:27017 which is not available in the container. You might want to change it to connect to mongo:27017 coz that's what it is linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your mongo is not set to autoconfigure. After a lot of hairpulling I realized that the my issue was not with containers, but Mongo autoconfigure, it will not connect to anything but localhost.

Create a Mongoclient, 
use that in a MongoFactory 
and use that in a MongoTemplate 
Annotate all of that wit a configuration annotation. 
Also exclude Mongo from Autoconfigure, that is how you will get a manual configure mongo.
Test it with profiles to test with different hostnames. Once you get that working
dockerize it and if your ports etc are properly done, you should be able to connect the two containers.